# Adding variable amount of elements(text boxs, drop down) dynamically MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'am having trouble adding multiple elements (text boxs, dropdownlist) to my form depending on the number selected in DropDownListFor.

the drop downlist is populated by the model using SelectListItem (see code below)

```
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberOfRooms,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["NumOfRooms"])%>
```

Can someone please point me into the right direction on how to dynamically add text boxes and dropdownlist? I need to retrieve the value of dynamically added text boxes in controller as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should write something that counts the selected values in your drop down list, save that value in a variable, and use a for loop based on it.

ex:

```
int count = 0;
for ( i=0; i<dropdown.length; i++ )
    if ( dropdown.getElement(i).selected == true )
        count++;
for ( i=0; i<count; i++ )
    make a textbox
```

Something similar to this should work. If this is not exactly what you are looking for, more details might help me better answer your question. Hope this helps!

Comment: How would you retrieve the selected value and call the forloop?

Comment: It depends on the programming language. Most have built in accessors like MyDropDownList.SelectedValue. Check your language's API to find out what call you should be making